# How to display prices on the site in different currencies?

Tags: php, mysql, database, design-patterns, database-design

The site has 5 currencies. The sales price of goods and delivery is set in euros. But the customer can choose the preferred currency to display prices.
A better solution would be to keep prices in all currencies in the table "prices" or convert dynamically?

Structure of table "prices":

- id
- currency
- variant_id
- value
- original_value

Comment: Conversion rates change often, so keep track of the conversion rate from your default currency and work it out dynamically. If you wanted to, you could cache these converted prices in a way you can regularly refresh them.

Comment: @Jonnix, currency rates will be updated on schedule at midnight and cached in redis. I can use these coefficients to convert dynamically, and I can also update prices at midnight in the "prices" table based on these coefficients. What solution will be more productive and correct from the point of view of architecture?

Comment: My default position would be to do it dynamically (so entirely personal opinion). The calculation is simple so not much processing, also immediate effect when the conversion rate has changed without relying on a second job. But there are arguments for pre-calculated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically.  It would be a simple `JOIN` plus a calculation.

However, ... It would be tempting to `ROUND(..,2)` when displaying.  This works for many Western currencies but does not work well for some of the Gulf states, which need 3 decimal places, or Korea, which does not really use Jeons any more.

If you need to round to a different number of places, use a Stored Function.  And/or perhaps the `JOIN` also gives the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depend on the business rule. If a price can be calculated by a simple conversion then store only price in some reference currency and convert it dynamically. However, you need a date to store rate history. When a price cannot be calculated dynamically you should store it. The combined approach may be used, too.